# Unknown column in where clause due to hyphens

Tags: php, mysql

having a slight issue with PHP that's aggravating me. I have an incredibly basic query which is called by PHP to find the corresponding article for this page. The URLs look a bit like this:

http://zconnect.org.uk/article/new-dead-island-screenshots

Which is rewritten from:

http://zconnect.org.uk/index.php?action=article&p=new-dead-island-screenshots

The query is pretty simple, and the code reads as follows:

```
$article = $_GET['p'];
$rowquery = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM articles WHERE friendlytitle = '$article'") or die(mysql_error());
```

However, this doesn't work. The error sprung up appears like this:

```
Unknown column 'new' in 'where clause'
```

But when you refresh the page, it seems to be working. I have absolutely no idea how to solve this issue, because it happens on every page on the first attempt to access it, but then seems to work fine after a refresh. Any idea how I can solve this issue?

Comment: One thing you might want to look into is http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php for sanitising the $_GET['p'] variable, your code is vulnerable to SQL Injection

Comment: now i see it works. if you get a correct answer on stack you should mark it as accepted (when you can) that way if you have any future questions people would be glad to help ^_^

Comment: @Neal, unfortunately though, it isn't working. Each time you try to load another page with the same URL format, it throws up an error, but works fine on refresh. I don't know why this is, but if you try another page, such as http://zconnect.org.uk/article/no-gears-of-war-for-japanese-or-germans you will see the error crop up again.

Comment: don't forget to run each and every $_GET through mysql_real_escape_string.

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
$article = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['p']);
```

[doc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php)

Comment: Like I wrote in the description, each page seems to throw up an error, but then works fine with a refresh. So if you try another page, such as http://zconnect.org.uk/article/fallout-new-vegas-patch-incoming or http://zconnect.org.uk/article/tales-of-monkey-island-collection-hits-retail you will see the error again.

Comment: Can we see your rewriting rule? Maybe there is something broken? And please try to echo out your $article variable (and if you took my advice and build the query in a seperate variable, echo this also).

Comment: RewriteRule ^article/([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?action=article&p=$1 [L]

Comment: It looks as if there might not be a fault with the hyphens at all, because I created an article with a single-word title that also seems to fail with the same error.

Comment: try using double quotes instead of single quotes: `"SELECT * FROM `articles` WHERE `friendlytitle` = \"$article\" LIMIT 1"`

Comment: No dice. SELECT * FROM `articles` WHERE `friendlytitle` = "videogame-nation-tour-sweeps-uk" LIMIT 1 results in Unknown column 'videogame' in 'where clause'

Comment: idk. the spire page is working now. there is something wrong and idk what it is'

Answer (score 2):

First, you should definitely escape $article, because the query string from $_GET[] is easy to manipulate. What i also prefer is to build the query within it's own variable (easier to debug, as you can echo the variable):

```
$article = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['p']);
$query = 'SELECT * FROM `articles` WHERE `friendlytitle` = "'. $article .'"';
$rowquery = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
```

EDIT: A bit late, I guess :)

Comment: Just did this. Query echoes like so:

SELECT * FROM `articles` WHERE `friendlytitle` = "burnout-paradise-review" LIMIT 1

Error still reads:

Unknown column 'burnout' in 'where clause'

Comment: I actually can't see where the problem is, atleast with the information / code you've posted so far. I've executed the Query in a test database and didn't encounter any errors. However, you could either replace - with _ (just in $article, though you have to make sure that you're saving `friendlytitle` with underscores. Or you can use the articles ID instead of the title (you have an auto-increment ID, right?). You should add the ID of the article to your URL (http://zconnect.org.uk/article/45/new-dead-island-screenshots). Now you don't need to save the articles "friendlytitle"....

Comment: ... and you won't encounter problems if 2 articles share the same title (if the "friendlytitle" is parsed out of the articles title?).

Comment: Backticks are pointless unless the field or table names are reserved words.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do 2 things:

1. Validate your input.  Right now anyone could submit anything making your code vulnerable to a [sql injection attack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)
2. Sanitize your input before making it part of your query

   $article = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['p']);

   Once you do these you will be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

Try escaping your code to avoid breaking your query with an apostrophe:

```
$article = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['p']);
$rowquery = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM articles WHERE friendlytitle = '$article'") or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: Didn't make a difference, unfortunately.